# Image loading issue on website using php codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, image, codeigniter

I hosted application live and application has many images.
Application has issue to load whole images so want to load first all content and after that images load.

Application has a carousel slider of products and when I scroll carousel, content already loaded but images load when I want to see next products.

So please suggest me how to do this ?

Comment: You probably need to elaborate on what you mean by "Application has issue to load whole site". What are you actually asking about?

Comment: Sorry , whole images